# LESS equivalent for selector variable evaluation

Tags: sass, less

Is it already possible to do something like this in LESS:

SASS:

```
$theme: a

.myselector-#{$theme}
  padding: 3px
```

This would evaluate in

```
.myselector-a
{
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: It is now possible.

This is an old question and has been re-answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280567/how-to-set-the-css-class-name-dynamically-in-lesscss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that this kind of feature is not supported yet...

I've just searched for it looking at LESS test files available on github (https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/tree/master/test/less) and didn't find such functionality.

Comment: I'll add a feature request then :)