# How to set the CSS class name dynamically in LessCSS?

Tags: css, less

I need to add a dynamic name to a CSS class to create a more specific decendent selector.

Here is my Less code:

```
@scope:  name;  //line1
.@scope .ui-widget{  color: #fff} //line2
```

But I am getting a parser error at line2.

Is there any way to set the CSS class name dynamically in LessCSS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Support was added to less.js and dotless in version 1.3

You have to use brackets and an escaping string.. e.g.

```
(~".@{scope} .another") { 
  color: #fff;
}
```

**Edit**

This format is deprecated. less 1.3.1 (currently just trunk build of less.js) supports a simpler syntax

```
.@{scope} .another-class {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: you may have to put the whole selector inside the quotes, I can't remember.

Comment: Works great, make sure to update to LessApp 2.7 (it wasn't working in 2.6)

Comment: How to do this with `&`? `&(~".@{scope}") { 
  color: #fff;
}` doesn't work.

Comment: the simpler syntax allows normal css around it, e.g. &.@{scope} should work

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code to get the expected output

```
@scope:  name;//line1
(~".@{scope} .ui-widget")  {  color: #ffbbff}  //line2
```